# meaning of 'bounce off'

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of 'bouncing off' in this context?

> Yes! In fact, that’s really why I called the book *Thinking Better*. Because I was sort of bouncing off that book of Kahneman’s, *Thinking, Fast And Slow*.

It's from [this transcript](https://freakonomics.com/podcast/frbc-thinking-better/).

Comment: Why are you self-vandalizing your question after having thanked the person who provided an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "I was using that book [Kahneman's] as inspiration, then adding/creating my own ideas based on those concepts".

In a similar vein, you will read sentences such as "I was bouncing ideas off Joe" to mean you were telling Joe your ideas and asking for feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is another relevant meaning of "bouncing off" meaning to struggle to understand or fail to understand.

> I was bouncing off Kant, so I switched to something less dense.